# nicht imperatives "haben" mit oder ohne "zu"

Tags: grammar

Die Beispielsituation:

Neben mir steht ein Kelchglas mit Wein auf dem Boden. Aus Ärger wirft jemand nun eine Packung Zellstofftaschentücher oder etwas ähnliches in meine Richtung. Nun möchte ich auf das Glas hinweisen.

> Ey, pass auf! Ich habe hier ein Glas (zu) stehen.

Für mich ist beides richtig (mit und ohne), würde aber die zu-Version sagen, aber ich kenne Leute die das "zu" als völlig falsch empfinden.

- Was ist richtig?

Comment: Das zu wird in Berlin, woher ich komme, verwandt, gilt aber als falsch im Hochdeutschen. Ich kann nur leider keine Quelle dafür nennen, daher nur dieser Kommentar.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz... Ich komme auch aus Berlin. Dann macht das ja Sinn

Comment: Sehr interessant, dass das in Berlin tatsächlich verwendet wird. Wieder was gelernt.

Comment: @Daniel, auf jeden Fall. Mein Deutsch war eigentlich nie schlecht, aber dass in diesen Fällen kein „zu“ zu verwenden ist, ist etwas, das ich erst spät gelernt habe.

Answer (score 2):

Das *zu* ist hier definitiv falsch.

Also (umgangssprachlich):

> Ich habe hier ein Glas stehen.

Du hast das Glas nicht *zu* stehen. Es steht von selbst.

Etwas anderes:

> Lass mich in Ruhe! Ich habe Arbeit *zu* erledigen.

Comment: Was drückt das "zu" den aus? Eine Begründung wäre schon schön.

Comment: @Emanuel: Du meinst das zweite Beispiel? Hier drückt das *zu* eine Notwendigkeit aus. *haben ... zu ...* = *müssen ...*

Comment: Ja, aber "zu" drückt nicht immer eine Notwendigkeit aus... "ich habe Lust, aufzustehen". Hier nicht. Wenn es also nicht immer eine Notwendigkeit ausdrückt, dann ist die Tatsache, dass in dem ersten Beispiel keine solche vorhanden ist, keine Begründung gegen "zu" und das ist, was mich stört.

Comment: Warum meinst Du, das erste wäre umgangssprachlich?

Comment: @Emanuel: Die Logik kann ich nachvollziehen - es stimmt, dass das keine Begründung gegen das *zu* im ersten Beispiel ist.

Comment: Warum darf *zu* hier nicht ein Modalverb darstellen? *Ich habe hier ein Glas* **zu** *stehen* ~ *Ich habe hier ein Glas, das stehen {Modalverb}*.

Answer (score 0):

Ich (Muttersprachler, Österreich) empfinde "zu" in diesem Beispiel definitiv als falsch bzw. unidiomatisch. Die Konstruktion lautet "ich habe" + Inifinitiv, also ich "ich habe etwas stehen".

Answer (score 0):

In Bayern würde das auch niemand sagen. Ich denke das gehört einfach zum Berliner Dialekt.

Aspekte eines Dialekts müssen nicht immer sinnvoll sein. In Bayern gibt es zum Beispiel die doppelte Verneinung "des dad i nia ned doa", die hochdeutsche Übersetzung "das würde ich nie nicht tun" wäre grammatikalisch auch völlig falsch.